# C#: Reflect class by its name stored in string variable

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I want to reflect model classes of a MVC project by its name which I have in a string variable ***refName***. Currently I am using switch case to use those class as template i.e <T>. How can we do this part better, so that if a new class comes in then I don't want to insert a new case in this switch statement.

Basically, what I want to do is to collect data from cosmos db into a specific template class format according to a field **gRefType**. Here's what I have done:

```
IEnumerable<Object> itemsRefDetail;
switch (refName)
{
     case "AMCaseStatus":
         itemsRefDetail = await DocumentDBRepository<AMCaseStatus>.GetItemRefDetailAsync(p => p.GrefType == refName && p.Tag == tag, collectionId);
         break;
     case "AMcaseSubStatus":
         itemsRefDetail = await DocumentDBRepository<AMcaseSubStatus>.GetItemRefDetailAsync(p => p.GrefType == refName && p.Tag == tag, collectionId);
         break;
     case "AMRole":
         itemsRefDetail = await DocumentDBRepository<AMRole>.GetItemRefDetailAsync(p => p.GrefType == refName && p.Tag == tag, collectionId);
         break;
}
```

As you can see in the above code, Template class used in each case is as same as case value. All the classes have both the properties(GrefType and Tag) in common.

Here is the DocumentDbRepository class:

```
public static class DocumentDBRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemRefDetailAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string collectionId)
    {
        IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, collectionId))
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

        FeedResponse<T> privilegeQueryResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();

        return privilegeQueryResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, with some reflection and big nasty Expression.Lambda

Comment: @Saruman can you please explain a little.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example of how to reflect generic types, The only thing you should do is, wrap up the `GrefType` and `Tag` into a baseclass/interface. This might give you a startup:

- The BaseType is the basetype of your data, which contains the fields you can use in your lambda function.
- Data is your data service (client.CreateDocumentQuery), in this case some test data.
- DocumentDBRepository contains the static SelectData method, which executes the lambda function passed as parameter.
- MyLookupThing is derived from the BaseType, used in reflection.
- TestReflection does the reflection and executes it.

Here's the code:

```
// The basetype of an item (which contains de RefName etc)
public class BaseType
{
    public string RefName { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
// static T service with some testdata (mock)
public static class Data<T> where T : BaseType
{
    public static List<T> MyData { get; } = new List<T>();

    static Data()
    {
        // create an item
        var item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        item.RefName = "Test";
        item.Tag = "Bla";
        MyData.Add(item);

        var item2 = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        item2.RefName = "SomethingElse";
        item2.Tag = "TagThing";
        MyData.Add(item2);

        var item3 = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        item3.RefName = "Test2";
        item3.Tag = "Bla2";
        MyData.Add(item3);
    }
}
```

---

```
// the generic class which uses the basetype as generic
public static class DocumentDBRepository<T> where T : BaseType
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectData(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        // some static test data
        return Data<T>.MyData.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

---

```
// your derived class from BaseType
public class MyLookupThing : BaseType
{

}
```

---

```
class TestReflection
{
    public TestReflection()
    {
        // you can create more classes derived from BaseType 
        var typeStr = "TestRef.MyLookupThing";

        // resolve the type:
        var lookupType = (from ass in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                          from t in ass.GetTypes()
                          where t.FullName == typeStr
                          select t).First();

        // get the type of the generic class
        var myType = typeof(DocumentDBRepository<>);

        // create a generic type
        var myGenericType = myType.MakeGenericType(lookupType);

        var method = myGenericType.GetMethod("SelectData", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        // Create the function (with the BaseType)
        var func = new Func<BaseType, bool>(item => item.RefName.StartsWith("Test"));

        // invoke the method of the generic class
        IEnumerable<BaseType> result = (IEnumerable<BaseType>)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { func });

        // show the results
        foreach (var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine(item.RefName);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

---

Which will give:

```
Test
Test2
```

as result

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can create this expression that limits the query to the type:

```
internal static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateTypeSpesificExpression<TEntity>(string refName) where TEntity : class
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IAmObject));
    var member = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(IAmObject.GrefType));
    var contant = Expression.Constant(refName);
    var body = Expression.Equal(member, contant);
    var extra = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parameter);
    return extra;
}
```

This is all assuming that your AM classes have the same interface.
Once you do that you can simple add this in your where clause.

Your query should look like this:

```
IEnumerable<Object> itemsRefDetail = await DocumentDBRepository<AMCaseStatus>.GetItemRefDetailAsync(p => CreateTypeSpesificExpression(refName) && p.Tag == tag, collectionId);
```

Also something worth pointing out is that [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) already has native support for type based collection sharing.